# Lua table to function arguments

Tags: lua, redis

I have a redis command that uses the format:

```
red:msetnx(key1, val1, key2, val2, key3, val3, ...)
```

I would like to set this up behind a function that takes a table of key / value pairs and runs that through `red:msetnx()` -- How would I reformat my table into an alternating key/value comma separated argument list and pass that to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make one table that has the keys and values in order, and pass it using `unpack`:

```
args = { 'key1', 'val1', 'key2', 'val2', 'key3', 'val3' }
red:msetnx(unpack(args))
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that there is a more readable way to do it.

```
function foo (t)
   local f = {}
   for k,v in pairs(t) do
      table.insert(f, k)
      table.insert(f, v)
   end
   return table.unpack(f) -- depends on lua version table.unpack() or unpack()
end
red:msetnx(foo({key1="val1", key2="val2" --[[and so on]]}))
```